# Best way to style label-over-field forms?

Tags: css, forms, label, standards

Say  you want a form with the following layout

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| Street Address 1              Street Address 2
|  _____________________         _____________________
| |_____________________|       |_____________________|
|
| City              State                 Zip
|  ______________    ____       _____________________
| |______________|  |___^|     |_____________________|
|
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I'm sure there's no more than a few community accepted "correct" ways of doing html/css for this yet every time I find myself having to style something like it I'm twiddling with widths, floats, nested label vs using `for=""`, etc.

What are good, generally accepted (meaning it's not ***just*** your opinion) approaches to creating the html and css and having it be semantically meaningful, maintainable, and work with browser re-sizing?

**Ed:**
I realize of course that there is no one technique that works for every situation. However, when you start creating a form you start with some sort of baseline, some sort of guidance - this is what I've been unable to find and what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I typically combine the label/input in a div and then group those into a container (typically a fieldset) that can be treated as a single unit.  Then you can have a consistent widths, floats, margins, etc.

I have also used classes in applying consistent sizing of labels and inputs - think (small,medium,large).

It could look like this:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="medium">
<label for="street1">Street Address 1</label>
<input id="street1" />
</div>
<div class="medium">
<label for="street2">Street Address 2</label>
<input id="street2" />
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<div class="small">
<label for="city">City</label>
<input id="city" name="city />
...
</fieldset>
```

If you are feeling really ambitiuos, then over time you can create your own 'Ultimate Package' [like Simon Collison](http://colly.com/comments/the_process_toolbox_part_one_backbone/) that you can use to jumpstart your projects.

Answer (score 1):

The technique presented in the link below is clean and semantic.

`label` tags enclose corresponding input elements.

`fieldset` tags enclose groups of input elements.

`ul` and `li` tags organize the form elements line by line.

Then everything is visually tweaked to perfection with CSS.

http://www.slideshare.net/AaronGustafson/learning-to-love-forms-web-directions-south-07

Note:  The bottom of some of the slides are clipped.  The whole presentation can be downloaded as an OpenOffice document where nothing is clipped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but can't you combine each label and the input in a pair of  and  tags, and by using proper css make the the way you want?

Comment: Amir, the question is not **how** to do this; there are a million ways. The question is what does the community accept as the correct way.

Comment: The community, insofar as there's ever a 'community' opinion is, I think: whatever works best for you and your use-case, which, ideally, doesn't murder semantics.

Comment: @George Mauer: That seems grounds for closure, even though you're not asking for ***just*** individual opinions...

Comment: @DavidThomas With all due respect (and I mean it, your answers have helped me in the past) that's a total cop-out that shirks any responsibility for giving guidance. I realize that everything does not work for every situation but there's a baseline that people start with. I do not have one that I'm happy with and this is what I am in search of.

Comment: @BoltClock - If there is a more appropriate forum then let me know, I think this is a bit too specific for programmers stackexchange. I am asking for guidance which I have not been able to find easily and satisfactorily online.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms) has a stacked forms component and was [developed as a style guide and toolkit](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/building-twitter-bootstrap/) so it's probably a reasonable working example of best practices (at least for those particular designers, obviously not for every single use-case everywhere).

The most consistent best-pratice I've seen for creating forms is to enclose both the label and the input in label tags to increase clickable area, thus making the form more usable.